# How to auto translate a full Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, plugins, package, translation

I have an existing app built in Flutter which supports only the English language right now. I want to extend the language support for multiple other languages and I dont want to individually translate each Text widget in the whole app as it can get tedious since its a big project. Is there any way I can translate my whole app using a plugin or a package? What would be the easiest way to translate my app all at once integrating multiple language support into it? Any help would be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

I tried using the translator package from pub.dev which individually translates each Text widget which is a very tedious task for the scale of the project I am currently working on.

Comment: try flutter localisation

Comment: the app has both static and dynamic text widgets i.e in the ui and from the api responses which doesnt make localisation an efficient way to translate the app. Also, again each text widget has to be modified for the translation to work.

Comment: google_translate: ^0.0.6
use this plugin and try

Comment: Doesnt google translate also require me to individually translate every text widget?

Comment: There is no efficient way to translate widgets in real-time by using a translator. You need to extract all texts by using a plugin like `language_helper` that has a feature to do it (you might be doing some more ways to make it work depending on the plugin you use). After that, you can translate those texts inside a single file easily by using a translator like Chat-GPT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slang_gpt](https://pub.dev/packages/slang_gpt), this library works with [slang](https://pub.dev/packages/slang) and [slang_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/slang_flutter) if you want to have rich text support.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little as to how the plugin works?

Comment: You will need to create a translation file for one language, and the plugin will use gpt to translate it and create a json file for another language, just read the plugins descriptions, it's very well detailed.